# Totally manual Android compile

Tags: java, android

I have always used ADT to develop Android applications, but have moved to a new machine which does not have ADT installed.  Google does not seem to support using ADT any more anyway, saying "you should migrate your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible".  But Android Studio apparently uses Gradle which requires an Internet connection to compile, which won't work for me when I'm on the road, when I can download stuff to install if needed, but don't have an Internet connection when I'm actually working.

So as a work-around I am exploring the idea of not using an IDE at all and just manually compiling everything.  (This also seems more future proof against the next time Google decides everyone needs to switch to a whole set of new tools.) I assume that to do this I need a few command line tools, for instance, something like "javac" to compile Java files into class files and next something to create  `dex` file(s) and finally something to package everything together into an apk and sign it.  However, when I search for instructions on manual builds I still find constant references to a build system such as Ant or Gradle.  I don't want to use any build system!

From scratch, what is the minimum I need in terms of tools I need to download and figure out the command line invocation to turn a simple (let's say "Hello World" simple) `java` file (and a few support files like a layout XML file and manifest) into a working APK? (Note that I need to build an APK that will work on APIs as old as API level 10.)

Update: Ok, so far I have installed the standalone SDK tools, and have used the SDK Manager to install the SDKs that I need.  But now I'm unsure of what commands I need to run: I'm familiar with `javac` and I see that, but I know there are other commands too.  Again, I have seen several SO questions asking about how to build and it refers to things like the `ant` or `android` command, which are NOT in the stand-along SDK tools and which shouldn't be necessary if I just knew which commands to invoke manually.

Comment: Gradle just uses the Internet to download dependencies, similar to `npm` or `RubyGems`. If you don't change your dependencies, you don't need an Internet connection to build.

Comment: Agree with @karaokyo. Compile it with android studio and before going offline goto File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Offline Work".